# How to find nature of algebraic graph?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, coordinate-systems

How to find nature of any algebraic graph when graph points are given?
Ex :

$x = (1,2,3,4)$

$y= (3,8,15,24)$

What is the nature of graph ?

P.S. I want to know short-cuts for all possible graphs?

Comment: You find the function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ such that $\exists$ a bijection between the sets $X$ and $Y$ - that will show the nature of the graph.

Comment: @BLAZE please elaborate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function that maps $x$ to $y$ is $$f(x)=2x+x^2$$ Such that $f(1)=3$, $f(2)=8$, $f(3)=15$ and $f(4)=24$. The nature of your graph is quadratic as $$f(x)=x(2+x)$$ it goes through the origin $(0,0)$ and intersects the axis at $x=-2$ and $x=0$ it has a minimum point at $(-1,1)$. Hope this helps.

Comment: If it's possible then give me the "general approach" for any questions!

Comment: @ GAURAV Its hard to give a general approach since every situation is unique. My only advice is to do what I did and find the connection between the numbers for $x$ and $y$ this is known loosely as a bijection and in our case the bijection was established by the function $$f(x)=x(2+x)$$.

Comment: Ok thanks for your efforts! But is there any logic to know only nature of curve in the above type of question so you are able to answer like it is  linear, quadratic, cubic, exponential.

Comment: @GAURAV the only logic you can use is that for which I told you already, but you can also find the intercepts of such graphs and find out their stationary points to find out the nature of the algebraic graph. From this you can draw the graph. Good luck to you and see you in the future :)